# WordPress in var/www/html not loading anything (on digital ocean)

Tags: wordpress, apache, lamp, digital-ocean

I'm trying to install my godaddy wordpress site on digital ocean from backup. I installed a digital ocean ubuntu droplet just as instructions described on digital ocean:

- install apache2, PHP, mysql, and wordpress.
- I added in my data to the mysql database, and it works because my /phpadmin link was accessible and my tables were present
- I set config to first look for index.php
- I copied all the wordpress files /wp-admin /wp-content /wp-includes and other files of that nature into the ~/var/www/html dir
- I copied the apache index.html file into ~/var/www

When I go to my site.com/ it goes to the /index.html apache file, but nothing else. On my local host I accessed /phpadmin but when I changed name servers example.com/phpadmin didn't work. I tried example.com/html/index.php or variations to no avail.

Here is my example.com.conf file, please let me know anything you think I missed:

exmaple.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.example.com
     Redirect permanent / http://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Note: When I did install WP new, it went into ~/root/wordpress if that matters

Comment: Not sure why my question was downvoted, but any advice would help!

Comment: Try checking `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was 2 fold:

My files should have been in the `var/www` dir and not the `var/www/html`, I don't know why because all tutorials say otherwise.

I didn't have permissions to be given to anyone having a GET request.
My friend helped me, I believe this is what he did in command prompt,

first in `var/www/html`

`cat /etc/pa`

`cat /etc/passwd | grep www`

`chown -R www-data:www-data ./`

then in `var/www`

`mv ./html/*.* ./`

`ls -aslh html/`

`rm -rf html/`

Answer (score 0):

First deleted default index.html file created by initial Apache install in /var/www/html/ directory and it worked... I know it's late, but added for future users